# clock() and CLOCKS_PER_SEC on OSX 10.7

Tags: c++, macos, clock, time.h

I'm having a problem using clock() in OSX.
I just want to display the time elapsed since my program started.
The thing is, when I divide the clock_t struct by CLOCKS_PER_SEC I get strange results.

Running my program for 10 seconds will display 1.0.
CLOCKS_PER_SEC is set to 1,000,000 on my system.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
    //startTime = clock() at the start of the program
    //This is called in each program loop       
    elapsedTime = (double)(clock() - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC
```

If I'm doing elapsedTime * 10 I get the accurate value in seconds.
I don't do any sleep or wait at all during the program execution.

Any help understanding what's happening would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok, I corrected the cast, but it doesn't change the fact that if I run the program for 10 seconds I get 1.0, 1 seconds is 0.1 . This is what I don't understand. My CLOCKS_PER_SEC is like a CLOCKS_PER_TEN_SEC.

Comment: Just what are you doing between the two `clock()` calls?

Comment: Just drawing a simple image with SFML. (no fps limit involved). I'm also displaying the elaspedTime on each frame, and I see each second adds about 0.1 to  the elapsedTime.

Comment: Then maybe most of the processing is being done by the GPU and not being counted by `clock()`.

Comment: Didn't think about that. But I don't know how I can verify it. I just found SFML has a Clock class, I think I'll stick with it, but still don't understand why I get something pretty accurate by multiplying elapsedTime by 10.

Answer (score 2):

I think your cast is in the wrong place, so you're getting an integer division. Try this:

```
elapsedTime = (double)(clock() - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

EDIT:

Also note that on most systems, `clock()` measures CPU time. Maybe you're not using as much CPU time as you think.

Answer (score 0):

move your cast to the inside of the first parenthesis:

```
 elapsedTime = ((double)(clock() - startTime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
```

Now `clock() -startTime` becomes double, forcing CLOCKS_PER_SEC to be a floating point value too, and you get floating point result. Otherwise, it's an integer divide, and you get only integer results.

Answer (score 0):

clock() with CLOCKS_PER_SEC is not fit for purpose on Mac OS X. clock() returns the processor time in ticks, while POSIX stipulates that CLOCKS_PER_SEC is 1000000, as noted in the man clock page.

In my case of running into this, like you, the calculation is off by a factor of ten. So, clock() is running at 100000 clocks per second. On Windows, I'm seeing 1000 clocks per second. But if you check into this, the actual resolution and precision can be far worse than this, so clock() is not a good solution in general. For Mac OS X, gettimeofday is a much better solution. I also suppose std::chrono is a good solution, and should be a better cross platform choice, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: If you decide to try `chrono`, here's a video tutorial to help get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M :-)  However, `chrono` will only measure elapsed time, not processor time like `clock()` does.

Comment: Yes, in my case I'm only interested in elapsed time, roughly millisecond accuracy. And you are right, I hadn't noticed that although clock() under Windows is defined as "wall-clock time", the unix version is processor time. (I was using gettimeofday on the Mac side from the start, but went to clock() for the Windows builds—I was just experimenting to see if I could use clock() and avoid minor conditional compilation ugliness.) The bottom line is clock() is very rough on Windows, and on Mac it's the wrong thing. Obviously, chrono is the best cross-platform choice.

Comment: FWIW, a one-liner for the current time in milliseconds (#include <chrono>):

std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();